# Invalid procedure call or argument error in vba for editing files from dir

Tags: vba

I have below code which I have minimized just to keep important lines. I'm geting error `Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument` at `StrFile = Dir`

The code below checks the `.py` files from given directory and adds content into it. Using the same name it searches `.seq`, `.xml` and `.macro` at same location and also replaces content. But I have to handle 2 cases.

1. In case of '.xml', sometimes it will not exists so I need to skip the related code.
2. Same goes with '.macro'. Sometimes it does not exist, need to skip it and sometimes it is present and could be multiple for same test case having _1, _2 as suffix. I have handled both cases using `If` condition. But getting above error.

I would appreciate your help.

```
Dim pypath, path, aName, StrFile, history, sTemp1 As String

Dim myFile          As String
Sub InternalData_Header()
    
path = "C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\2"
    
    testcount = 0
    
    ' Dim StrFile   As String
    StrFile = Dir(path & "\*.py")
    
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Dim sBuf    As String
        Dim sTemp   As String
        Dim iFileNum As Integer
        Dim sFileName As String
        
        ' Edit      as needed
        sFileName = path & "\" & StrFile
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
        sTemp = ""
        Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
            Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
            sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
        Loop
        Close iFileNum
        
        ''' Skip loop if autotest name is not found in a row
        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "Autotest name Not found"
            'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        End If
        
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
        Print #iFileNum, sTemp
        Close iFileNum
        StrFile = Dir '''' Error at this line: Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument
        
        '''' Add history line in .seq files ===============================================
        sFileName = path & "\" & Arr1(0) & ".seq"
        
        Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
        sTemp = ""
        Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
            Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
            If InStr(1, sBuf, "   Initial") Then
                seqHist = sBuf
            End If
            sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
        Loop
        Close iFileNum
        
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
        Print #iFileNum, sTemp
        Close iFileNum
        
        '''' Add history line in .xml files ===============================================
        Dim strFileExists2 As String
        sFileName2 = path & "\" & Arr1(0) & "--master.xml"
        'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        strFileExists2 = Dir(sFileName2)
        If strFileExists2 = "" Then
            ''' .xml file does not exists, skip
        Else
            Open sFileName2 For Input As iFileNum
            Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
                Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf1
                sTemp1 = sTemp1 & sBuf1 & vbCrLf
            Loop
            ''' xml history line
            Close iFileNum

            iFileNum = FreeFile
            Open sFileName2 For Output As iFileNum
            Print #iFileNum, sTemp1
            Close iFileNum
        End If
        
        '''' Add history line in .macro files ===============================================
        Dim macroCount As Long
        Dim strFileExists1 As String
        macroCount = 1
        For macroCount = 1 To 5 ''' Check upto 5 macro files whether they are present, if yes,  make changes
            'sFileName = path & "\" & StrFile
            sFileName1 = path & "\" & Arr1(0) & "_" & macroCount & ".macro"
            strFileExists1 = Dir(sFileName1)
            
            If strFileExists1 = "" Then
            Else
                iFileNum = FreeFile
                Open sFileName1 For Input As iFileNum
                sTemp = ""
                Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
                Loop
                Close iFileNum
                ' macro history line
                
                iFileNum = FreeFile
                Open sFileName1 For Output As iFileNum
                Print #iFileNum, sTemp
                Close iFileNum
            End If
            
        Next macroCount
        macroCount = 1
        lcol = 0
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use Dir to check whether a file exists when you're in the middle of enumerating the files in a folder using Dir.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasHunter for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way. This would be the preferred solution if you were creating new files in the folder you're iterating.

```
Dim pyFiles As New Collection
Dim fnm as Variant

fnm = Dir(path & "\*.py")
do while fnm <> ""
    pyFiles.add path & "\" & fnm
    fnm = Dir
loop

for each fnm in pyfiles
    if Dir(fnm) <> "" then
        ' process file
    end if
next pyfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below `FileSystemObject` approach from this [link](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-filesystemobject/) I could resolve the error.

```
Sub CheckFileExist()
Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject
    If MyFSO.FileExists("C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\Test\Test.xlsx") Then
        MsgBox "The File Exists"
    Else
        MsgBox "The File Does Not Exist"
    End If
End Sub
```